# Dots and boxes, even chains for 1st player, suggest move

Tags: algorithm, 2d-games

I got to know that on a board of 3x3 box, player 1 should try to make even number of long chains. (long chain is a chain of length 3 or more). [source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KboGyIilP6k)

**To summarize:**  ([credit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10783/12703))

*I need an even number of chains
I am player one, as an even number of moves has been made, and there are an even number of dots.
(This is known as the chain rule, and anyone who is unfamiliar with it should learn it as it is a key to winning dots and boxes. The number of squares already in chains means the winner of the chains battle in this game wins the majority of the squares by sacrificing two at the end of each of the chains they are given.)*

I have been trying to play the game on [this site](http://dotsandboxes.org/) but have been unable to win so far.

Attaching the board configuration when I got an even number of chains and its my turn to move.

[image]

What should be my move?

Can you give a winning strategy against the bot on this site?

What am I missing here? It seems to me that even though I got even number of long chains, no matter what move I make I will end up losing.

Comment: I think there is an added constraint here, that is it should be opponent's turn after even number of chains. i.e. my move should result in an even number of chains.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't follow the YouTube link (readable text preferred) and don't know about the long chains. E.g., shouldn't we treat cycles differently from paths?

Still, in the given position, you can move anywhere on the right, giving the three right squares to your opponent and then taking the remaining six squares after his move.

Comment: The opponent will take only 1 square and give 2. This way he will get all 6. Check out the wikipedia link -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes

Comment: also added summary of the youtube link

Comment: @rents Thank you for the link and the textual explanation! My answer is indeed a novice play, i.e., bad.